# Why is argument passed in {} parenthesis in React Native's renderItem function associated with Flat List

Tags: javascript, react-native

In this particular example

```
   const rows = [
  {id: 0, text: 'View'},
  {id: 1, text: 'Text'},
  {id: 2, text: 'Image'},
  {id: 3, text: 'ScrollView'},
  {id: 4, text: 'ListView'},
]

const extractKey = ({id}) => id

export default class App extends Component {

  renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.row}>
        {item.text}
      </Text>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        style={styles.container}
        data={rows}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={extractKey}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 20,
    flex: 1,
  },
  row: {
    padding: 15,
    marginBottom: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
  },
})
```

provided at http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/flatlist,

Why is the renderItem being assigned a function that take ({item}) instead of just (item)? 
Aren't arrow function supposed to work by taking arguments in "()"? Whats the significance of "{}" here? Removing them causes the text in each FlastList item to be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a feature of ES6 called **Destructuring**

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
>   makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from
>   objects, into distinct variables.

*[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)*

Basically it's a shortcut syntax to directly get access to a key inside an object passed as parameter of a function.

**Example** :

```js
const foo = {
  bar: "hello world"
};

function basic(arg) {
  const bar = arg.bar;
  console.log(bar);
};

function destructuring({bar}) {
// no need to define a bar variable here, bar is already avalaible !
  console.log(bar);
};

basic(foo);
destructuring(foo);
```